# streamlit.errors.StreamlitAPIException: `seek()` is not a valid Streamlit command

Tags: python-3.x, streamlit

I am trying to pass the image to my function `loadImage`:

```
def loadImage(image):
    np_image = Image.open(image)
    np_image = np.array(np_image).astype('float32') / 255
    np_image = transform.resize(np_image, (224, 224, 3))
    #  np_image = np.expand_dims(np_image, axis=0)
    return np_image
```

When I try to pass the Image read from the Streamlit Image then it gives me the following error:

```
raise StreamlitAPIException(message)
streamlit.errors.StreamlitAPIException: `seek()` is not a valid Streamlit command.
```

My Main Function command:

```py
list = predictions(model=model, breed_list=breed_list, image=st.image(img))
```

Prediction Function:

```py
def predictions(model, breed_list, image):
    probabilities = model.predict(helper.loadImage(image))
    return probabilities
```

Loading image

```
img_file = st.sidebar.file_uploader(label='Upload a file', type=['png', 'jpg'])
    if img_file:
        img = Image.open(img_file)
```

[Full Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQtW7.png)

Comment: What is img? that you are passing to st.image()

Comment: pass the **image dir** to  `loadImage(image=<imag source>)` for example `loadImage(image="imgs/fgshs.png")`

Comment: img_file = st.sidebar.file_uploader(label='Upload a file', type=['png', 'jpg'])
    if img_file:
        img = Image.open(img_file)

Answer (score 0):

[`Image.open()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open) is expecting a filename, `pathlib.Path`, or IO-like object, but you're passing it the output of `st.image(img)`, which is going to be a Streamlit DeltaGenerator object (essentially a Streamlit element). As the output of `st.image(img)` is not a filename (i.e. string) and is not a `pathlib.Path` object, `Image.open()` is assuming it to be an IO-like object, hence why it's trying to call the `.seek()` method (which DeltaGenerator objects don't provide, which then caused the error).

Judging by your code, I assume `img` represents the filename of some image you want to display. If this is this case, you might want to change your code so as to load the image into a numpy array first, then render the loaded image in Streamlit, then make your predictions from it:

```py
def loadImage(image):
    np_image = Image.open(image)
    np_image = np.array(np_image).astype('float32') / 255
    np_image = transform.resize(np_image, (224, 224, 3))
    #  np_image = np.expand_dims(np_image, axis=0)
    return np_image

def predictions(model, breed_list, image):
    probabilities = model.predict(loadImage(image))
    return probabilities

loaded_img = loadImage(img)
st.image(img)
list = predictions(model=model, breed_list=breed_list, image=loaded_img)
```

Additionally, and as an aside: to reduce confusion, I would strongly recommend renaming `list` in `list = predictions(...)` to something that doesn't conflict with the Python built-in `list`, perhaps to something like `predicted`.

Comment: can guide me more

Comment: I see you've updated your question to describe where you're getting the image from, and how you're loading it.

It seems you've got multiple issues going on. First, what I addressed: you need to render the image to Streamlit independently of passing it to `predictions()`.

Second, you're loading the image ("`img = Image.open(img_file)`"), then passing that loaded image into `loadImage` where `Image.open()` is called again on the already-loaded image. Don't do that. Just do `img = loadImage(img_file)` and everything should work.